# Are these Wave Equations correct and how do I figure out if solutions will diverge?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I am currently working on a simulation of Maxwell's equations for inhomogeneous media, i.e. for position-dependent $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$. For such a situation, Maxwell's equations read

$$
\nabla \cdot E = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rho - \left( \nabla \bar{\epsilon} \right) \cdot E \tag{I}
$$

$$
\nabla \cdot B = 0 \tag{II}
$$

$$
\nabla \times E = - \frac{\partial B}{\partial t} \tag{III}
$$

$$
\nabla \times B = \mu_{0} J + \mu_{0} \sigma E + \epsilon \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} \tag{IV}
$$

where $\bar{\epsilon}$ is the natural logarithm of $\epsilon$. From these equations I have derived the wave equations

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} E}{\partial t^{2}} + \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\mu_{0} \epsilon} \nabla^{2} E - \frac{1}{\epsilon} \frac{\partial J}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{\mu_{0} \epsilon_{s} \epsilon} \nabla \rho + \frac{1}{\mu_{0} \epsilon} \mathcal{H}_{\bar{\epsilon}} \cdot E + \frac{1}{\mu_{0} \epsilon} \mathcal{J}^{T}_{E} \cdot \nabla \bar{\epsilon}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} B}{\partial t^{2}} + \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\mu_{0} \epsilon} \nabla^{2} B + \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left( \nabla \times J \right) + \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left[ \left( \nabla \sigma \right) \times E \right] + \left(\nabla \bar{\epsilon} \right) \times \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}
$$

where $\mathcal{H}_{\bar{\epsilon}}$ indicates the Hessian of $\bar{\epsilon}$, and $\mathcal{J}_{E}$ is the Jacobian of the electric field, containing the derivatives of all components of $E$ with respect to the three spatial coordinates.

I have two questions: Are these equations correct?
How do I figure out if their solution, for given charge and current densities $J$ and $\rho$, diverge or not?

My simulation does diverge at some point, but I am unsure whether this is due to numerical instabilities, or if it is something that an (impossible to find) analytical solution would also do. Divergence, in this case, means that, at some point, the fields start growing exponentially in magnitude. What is odd though is the fact that even though their magnitude diverges, they still switch in polarity locally, i.e. go through a zero point periodically.

If my derivations or further informations are necessary, please ask away (I dont know how to properly copy latex formulas into here so I will probably link to a pdf).

Comment: Why not solve the first order equations on a Yee grid using FDTD, instead of solving the second order equations. You will find many resources online. It is the standard method IMO.

Comment: @AnonPhoton Thank you for the hint, I will look into it!

Comment: Look into computational photonics, preferably an introductory lecture. I would guess the second order approach to be a numerical nightmare....

Comment: If you tell us a bit more about the spectrum you are interested in, one can also simplify the problem. Most importantly ignore magnetization if it is optical.

Comment: Copying latex works if you put dollar signs before and after the equation (one for in line and two for ususal equation environment)

Comment: The application of the simulation is in a 7T MRI scenario for in-vivo imaging. The fields are generated using multiple dipole antennas around the human tissue, at around 300MHz. While the coils do create spin excitation from their alignment to an external B-field, this effect is small enough that mu can be considered to be constant everywhere, so I only have to deal with induced currents by the E-field because of nonzero sigma within the tissue, and the spatially varying epsilon. I dont know if this is considered an optical scenario

Comment: This sounds very interesting. I will try to give a more detailed answer when I have more time. Just one more thing regarding divergence: I mean when I think physically about energy content, I expect no divergent fields if the disturbance (charge/current) is finite in strength and time

Comment: Thank you for your offer! In a physical context, divergence doesnt make sense for the scenario I'm trying to simulate, which so far is a single dipole antenna sending out a sinusoidal wave into a spherical "phantom" i.e. a sphere with sigma = 0.22 S/m and epsilon = 100*epsilon_0, which is approximately correct for human tissue. For around 15 periods, the simulation does very well, but then at some point it starts growing exponentially. I will definitely try to learn about FDTD/Yee grid, and re-implement it, because as you said, second order is a nightmare, the CUDA kernel is 300 lines long

Comment: So this is definitely no optical scenario if we are talking MHz, your fields are varying so slowly that actually currents can be excited in the tissue I believe. But I think your tissue has vanishing charge density, so you can ignore $\rho$? Note that your equation IV assumes that $µ=1$ (is this true?!) and your equation I looks wrong to me, you should have $\rho=\nabla \vec{D}=\epsilon_0\nabla(\epsilon\vec{E})=\epsilon_0(\epsilon\nabla\vec{E}+\vec{E}\nabla{\epsilon})$. Anyways the  problem seems very much solvable using home made FDTD if you know your exciting $J$ which model your antennas.

Comment: $\rho$ in the equation is there to model the charge densities that arise in the dipole antennae (they act like LC circuits, building up charge on both ends). In FDTD calculations, is it enough to only use the $J$, and ignoring the $\rho$ arising at the same time? The $\rho$ within the dielectric human tissue can be ignored as far as I know (I'm no MRI expert, my dad works in that field and we're working on a project together). Also, since $J$ in the dipole antennas is "monochromatic", i.e. just a single sine, would it be sufficient to do a single frequency in a frequency domain simulation?

Comment: Doesnt $\rho = \epsilon_0(\epsilon\nabla\vec{E}+\vec{E}\nabla\epsilon)$ rearrange into the same equation I have? In my equation, $\bar{\epsilon}=\text{ln}(\epsilon)$, and I take the factor $\epsilon_0$ into the definition of $\epsilon$, so $\epsilon$ isnt the relative but the absolute permittivity.

Comment: In general, for FDTD simulations, can I just take the curl equations I have (III and IV) and use those for the stepping?

Comment: Model your antenna by a varying current or by the charge density. If you at the same time include the time varying charge density and the current you include the antenna twice. Yes the eq. is right if $\bar{\epsilon}$ is the natural logarithm the bar is non-standard notation and I did not read the definition carefully.

Comment: Yes you take those equations for stepping. Of course you will also need to ensure the divergence conditions, but I think if the initial fields/sources are divergence free one can proof that the fields stay divergence free if working on a Yee grid - There was something along these lines in my course on this. But I don't remember the details. Check the literature please.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! I'm watching a set of lectures currently, and I think you've led me in a very good direction!